# How to prevent a custom editorwindow from autoopening on editor launch?

Tags: unity-game-engine

I have a custom Editor window implementation that's autoopening on launch, but there's a bug that's causing it to hang my whole editor. Is there a config/pref file I can delete, before I run the editor, to keep it from autoopening?

I've already deleted my Editor preferences and playerprefs files with no luck :(
I'd like to just go back to the Default window layout before I launch the editor.

Comment: Have you tried removing the code that shows the window?

Comment: Have you tried launching in safe mode? You should be able to enter this mode by introducing a compiler error in any of your scripts while the editor is closed and then opening the editor?

Comment: You could also put a `return` statement at the top of `OnGUI` to prevent your gui code from running (if your issue is happening there and not in OnEnable or elsewhere).  Then you can close the window.

Answer (score 0):

I finally figured it out. First of all I did disable the code that shows the window (in our case EditorWindow.GetWindow), but it was still being spawned by my default layout.

Since that didn't work, I deleted my window class altogether, thus triggering Safe Mode. At this point my question is answered but my editor was still hanging, so I attached my debugger and noticed that one of my threads was doing adb-related IO calls. That's when I realized that I had a dev Android tablet connected via USB. As soon as I disconnected my device my editor started working again.